# I want to Scrape the button text using Beautifulsoup and python but it gives the error `'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'`

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I want to Scrape the button text using Beautifulsoup and python but it gives the error `'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'`

```
<button on="tap:tooltip-byline" class="jsx-2685183021 triggerText">JT Genter</button>
```

Here is the code I try

```
#Author
Author = soup.find('button', class_="jsx-2685183021 triggerText").text
print("Author: ", Author )
```

Comment: your code works for me on simple example - but maybe first use `print()` to check what you really get from server.

Comment: you may have the most common problem: page may use `JavaScript` to add/update elements but `BeautifulSoup`/`lxml`, `requests`/`urllib` can't run `JS`. You may need [Selenium](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/)  to control real web browser which can run `JS`. OR use (manually) `DevTools` in `Firefox`/`Chrome` (tab `Network`) to see if `JavaScript` reads data from some URL. And try to  use this URL with `requests`. `JS` usually gets `JSON` which can be easy converted to Python dictionary (without `BS`). You can also check if page has (free) `API` for programmers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for a button with classes `"jsx-2685183021 tooltip"` while actual button having classes `"jsx-2685183021 triggerText"`. Hopefully changing tooltip to triggerText will solve the issue.

--- Edit:
This is how i tested it:

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

resp_text = '<button on="tap:tooltip-byline" class="jsx-2685183021 triggerText">JT Genter</button>'
soup = BeautifulSoup(resp_text, "html.parser")
Author = soup.find('button', class_="jsx-2685183021 triggerText").text
print("Author: ", Author )
```

Comment: No still not working

Comment: Sorry to hear that. I've tested it on my side with the text you provided and it works after changing the class. Maybe there is something else missing before the code that you didn't share.

Comment: I've added the way i wrote the script to the answer so that it might help you somehow. Good luck!

Comment: This is the article link, it does not work here https://thepointsguy.com/guide/award-travelers-guide-to-marriott-bonvoy/

Comment: If you go to the article, you will see that now the button has classes `"jsx-3438354178 triggerText"`. As you see the one starting with jsx has changed. So most probably owners of the website is renaming classes dynamically in some periods. So you have to develop a new strategy to capture the button regarding this dynamic behaviour.

Comment: @InfoRewind when I run this url then it have class with different number `jsx-3438354178 triggerText` - and it shows that server may send different HTML in different moments - and this can make problem. Maybe you shoud search i.e `{"on": "tap:tooltip-byline"}` or maybe only `class_="triggerText"`. Or maybe you should use `.select(css_selection)` to create more complex selection.